For each Stack Exchange site, would it be good to have a pseudo-dictionary webpages for tag list?
For each Stack Exchange site, would it be good to have a pseudo-dictionary web page for tag list?
Essentially, it is a dictionary web page(s) containing a list of pages used by a particular Stack Exchange site along with a brief description of the purpose for a particular tag name.  Is that OK?

I am using a mobile smart phone, and I can Nit see it on stackexchange mobile sies

*not see it it is

What is a "a pseudo-dictionary web page for tag list"? A page with every single tag on it (or spread over several pages)? Which pages should be listed? What would be the criteria for their inclusion? Can you elaborate? Can you provide one or more examples for illustration? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** without *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now)

Tags already have tag wikis, so why would this be necessary?


On a small screen such as a phone there is a three bar menu on the top left of the page. If you tap on that you will see Tags in the dropdown menu. Choose that to see a page with the description and purpose of the site tags.

On a wider screen there is a sidebar on the left of the page with Tags in it.



On a wider screen with the Left Navigation sidebar disabled you can also use the three bar menu. Or if keyboard shortcuts are enabled press G and then T.
